# Почему  полдень в 12 часов?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Здравствуйте! Почему у нас 11 часов - это утро, а 12 - уже полдень? И что слово "полдень" означает - полдня, или может полный день?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значение слова Полдень по Ефремовой:
Полдень - 1. Середина дня, время высшего стояния солнца над горизонтом, соответствующее 12 часам дня. // перен. разг. Середина жизненного пути, конец молодости. 
2. Момент прохождения центра Солнца через меридиан данного места.

Полдень в Энциклопедическом словаре:
Полдень - момент верхней кульминации центра Солнца (т. е. достиженияСолнцем максимальной высоты над горизонтом при его суточном движении). http://tolkslovar.ru/p12480.html

Вот здесь интересные рассуждения: http://ru.encydia.com/en/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C

И вот здесь:http://shkolazhizni.ru/archive/0/n-29521/

Answer (score 2):

> И что слово "полдень" означает - полдня, или может полный день?

Да в общем-то ни то ни другое не далеко от истины. Но исторически, конечно, полдень - "пол дня". День здесь надо понимать как светлое время суток. Аналогично - полночь.

Когда же мы рассуждаем о времени суток, то неявно делим сутки на четыре составляющих - утро, день, вечер и ночь. При этом не все это делают одинаково в плане начала и окончания этих периодов. Но чаще всего используют астрономическое определение - день от 12:00 до 18:00 - и далее по 6 часов на каждый период.

> Почему у нас 11 часов - это утро, а 12 - уже полдень?

У кого "у нас"? Повторю, можно по разному трактовать. Особенно когда сейчас в России астрономический зональный полдень отстает от принятого поясного на 2 часа.

Answer (score 0):

> Почему **у нас** 11 часов - это утро, а 12 - уже полдень?

Потому что эти значения из двух разных классификаций.
Полдень - это астрономическая классификация времени суток. В Москве полдень в среднем за год наблюдается в 12:30. По этой классификации утро - это утренние сумерки, которые длятся от нескольких минут на экваторе до нескольких дней на полюсах.

> В современном деловом этикете «доброе утро» рекомендуется говорить в
> промежуток с 8 до 11 часов (Википедия).

Утро до 11:00 - это бюрократическая классификация. В ней время полдня не определено.
Таким образом, парадоксальность вопроса обусловлена смысловой ошибкой употребления терминов из разных классификаций.

P.S. Извините за занудство. Весьма маловероятна альтернативная версия возникновения парадоксальности вопроса - выделенное мной словосочетание "у нас" относится к одному человеку, страдающего раздвоением личности.